i with the lua script in the logitech g hub program
Tell me how can I make my script run indefinitely when I hold down the left mouse button until I release the left mouse button. I tried using chatgpt, but it gave crooked answers and nothing worked.
function main()
    -- Define the number of repetitions
    local repetitions = 10

    for i = 1, repetitions do
        -- Mouse left button down
        PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)  -- Left down
        Sleep(30)                       -- Delay 30 ms

        -- Mouse left button up
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)           -- Left up
        Sleep(5)                        -- Delay 5 ms

        -- Move the mouse
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)         -- Move right 0, down 2
    end
end

main()

And that's what chatgpt gave me:
-- Define the number of repetitions
local repetitions = 10

function main()
    OutputLogMessage("Hold 'LMB' to run the script. Release to stop.\n")

    while true do
        -- Check if the left mouse button is held down
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            OutputLogMessage("LMB is pressed. Running actions...\n")
            
            for i = 1, repetitions do
                -- Mouse left button down
                PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)  -- Left down
                Sleep(30)                       -- Delay 30 ms

                -- Mouse left button up
                ReleaseMouseButton(1)           -- Left up
                Sleep(5)                        -- Delay 5 ms

                -- Move the mouse
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)         -- Move right 0, down 2
            end
            
            -- Optionally, log that the actions are complete
            OutputLogMessage("Completed %d repetitions.\n", repetitions)
            
            -- Optional: Wait a moment before checking the button again
            Sleep(100)  -- Delay to prevent rapid retriggering
        end

        Sleep(10)  -- Prevent high CPU usage when the button is not pressed
    end
end

main()

Yes, it works, but not the way I need it.

That question is very similar to your.  Does that answer solve your problem?
